# How to align view in end without using nested column in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show view `Text 1`, `Text 2` at **Start** position and `Text 3` at **End** position. Something like this image

[image]

I did with the help of this logic

```
@Composable
fun XyzContent(isVisible: Boolean) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(
            text = "Text 1",
            style = SlateTypography.body1,
        )
        Text(
            text = "Text 2",
            style = SlateTypography.body1,
        )
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = isVisible) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Text 3",
                    style = SlateTypography.body1,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to avoid nested `Column` inside `AnimatedVisibility`. so I passed directly modifier in the `AnimatedVisibility` and remove `Column`, but now it's not working correctly. It showing me `Text 3` at **Start** position.

```
@Composable
fun XyzContent(isVisible: Boolean) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(
            text = "Text 1",
            style = SlateTypography.body1,
        )
        Text(
            text = "Text 2",
            style = SlateTypography.body1,
        )
        AnimatedVisibility(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(End),
            visible = isVisible
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Text 3",
                style = SlateTypography.body1,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this

[image].

So what is the best way to avoid this nested `Column` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `.fillMaxWidth()` from the `AnimatedVisibility`'s modifier. If that text gets the entire width, it doesn't have a chance to align itself to the end (*actually, you could also do that by changing the text alignment, but it's specific to text and doesn't seem to be necessary here).

You can try this:

```
@Composable
fun XyzContent(isVisible: Boolean) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(
            text = "Text 1",
            style = SlateTypography.body1,
        )
        Text(
            text = "Text 2",
            style = SlateTypography.body1,
        )
        AnimatedVisibility(
            modifier = Modifier.align(End),
            visible = isVisible
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Text 3",
                style = SlateTypography.body1,
            )
        }
    }
}
```